# Python SHA512encryption with PHP

Tags: php, python, encryption, sha512

This is the first time I am trying to deal with a python code. My client has recently gave me a python code:

```
python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("Pa55w0rd!", "$6$x88yEvVg")'
```

Which is used to encrypt the password, in the above code.

The password is **Pa55w0rd!** and the salt value is **x88yEvVg** . Can I execute the above code in PHP? I have tried doing this:

```
echo exec(`python -c "import crypt;print crypt.crypt('Pa55w0rd!', '\$6\$x88yEvVg\')"`);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`popen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) or [`proc_open`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php).

For example:

```
$password = 'Pa55w0rd!';
$salt = '$6$x88yEvVg';
$handle = popen('python -c \'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("' . $password . '", "' . $salt . '")\'', 'r');
$text = fread($handle, 100);
echo $text;
pclose($handle);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your code exactly works. How can I replace 'Pa55w0rd!' & 'x88yEvVg' with a variable?

Comment: @NewPHP, I updated the example code. (Use string operation). You may have to escape if password/salt string contain quote(`"`).

Answer (score 0):

Do you absolutely need to encrypt using python? Depending on your PHP version you could do this for PHP >= 5.3:

```
openssl_digest("Pa55w0rd!"."$6$x88yEvVg", "sha512");
```

and this for PHP 5.2 or 5.1

```
hash("sha512", "Pa55w0rd!"."$6$x88yEvVg");
```

This assumes that your salt value is just being concatenated with your password value.